# ActiveRecord::Store without accessors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, accessor

Is there a way to use [ActiveRecord::Store](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html) without declaring accessors?

Use case is that I want users to be able to append any variable to a URL and then have that key/value saved along with the record.

For instance, someone might do:
`http://example.com/response?order_number=12345&manager=Johnny&used_valet=true`

So I'd want `order_number`, `manager`, and `used_valet` to be saved in a `variables` column for a record. But every user would have a different set of variables they'd want stored.

Right now, I've got this:

```
class Response < ActiveRecord::Base
  store :variables
end
```

But doing that throws an `unknown attribute` error:

```
$ Response.create(order_number: '12345')
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: order_number
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't able to pass it in the constructor, you'll have to set each variable independently. See the line here where the country value is being set: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html

You should be able to loop through the params object to get all the parameters from the query string, then for each parameter set the settings attribute.